# How can i add an 'unversioned file' to github?

Tags: android-studio, github, version-control

I am trying to use GitHub for the first time and have managed to upload a small project i am working on.

The problem is that all of my files but one are being added to GitHub - i created this file after committing the project and have tried right clicking and 'ADD' but this does not seem to work.

Does anyone have any ideas of what the problem could be? I understand this is probably a fault on my behalf, i am just not able to figure out what i must do to rectify it.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using "ADD" without "COMMIT" only informs git that the added file should be included in the next commit, but it doesn't trigger any action itself.

You need to commit the file after using "ADD" in order for it to be versioned.

So:

1. Right click on the file -> ADD
2. VCS Menu -> Commit changes

Your file should appear on the list with the tick next to it. Click commit and you are good to go.

Do you have a git bash? If no, I recommend installing it, then try:

1. Run Git bash -> go to your project directory
2. git status -> should produce sth like "Untracked files: "
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "YourMessage"
5. git push

This should add your file to git versioning and push it to the GitHub repository.

Comment: I did not explain my initial question properly my apologies. After I add the file I also attempt to commit as outlined in your answer but it is not working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "it is not working"? Do you get any status massage?

Comment: There is no error message - the file does not get added or uploaded to my GitHub repository.

Comment: I have updated the answer, try using the command line instead of gui

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I am still not sure why using pushing through Android studio does not upload newly created classes but i can use this method if need be it is not that much of an inconvenience. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I would like how to do the same thing in the terminal. I have tried git init but it didn't add the files. Would you mind sharing if you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this is there is no change seen.  Try making another change to the file, even if you just add spaces to the end of one of he lines. Then save and try the commit again.

I had the same problem after creating the repository and committing; the only file committed was the MainActivity.java file, all other files were showing as 'unversioned file'.

Make sure to change your Project Window view to 'Project'. 
Then right click your project and select Git --> +Add.
All files will be updated and the "unversioned" list will be gone.